# Capacitor voltage divider in quasi-DC circuit

Tags: capacitor, ac, dc, voltage-divider

In the below image, I show two circuits, both fed by 50Hz AC.

In the top circuit, it is possible to continuously draw current across the point marked in red.

Does that remain the case on the bottom circuit? If so, how does this work?

[EDIT] Also - would the voltages across both capacitors remain equal?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top circuit uses **half wave** rectification, C1 is only charged during the **positive** part of the sinewave at the input. C2 is only charged during the **negative** part.

The second circuit is a **full wave rectifier** so it charges on both positive and negative parts of the input voltage.

However you have not one capacitor, as is common in this configuration, but you have 2 capacitors in series.

That would work **if** you do not have a DC current flowing through the node between C1 and C2.

If such a current was slowing it would for example discharge C1 but also charge C2 at the same time. This would make the voltages across C1 and C2 **unequal**.

If this DC current causing imbalance is very small, you could place resistors in parallel with C1 and C2. It is not a very neat solution but can work in some situations.

So the voltages across the capacitors would remain equal only if you load the positive and negative supplies equally (no DC current between C1 and C2). But I would never rely on this unless I'm absolutely sure I can do that.

It is better to have a **centretap** connection on the transformer feeding this circuit and connect that centretap to the point between C1 and C2.

This is what is used when symmetrical supply voltages are needed.

[image]

Comment: The circuit is representing the input side of a switching power supply, so centre taps aren't exactly handy here.

I guess what I was wondering is, does the combination of a chopping input, and the properties of the capacitors allow a small amount of current to be drawn from that point without causing an imbalance (Without needing to balance that back with a voltage divider)

Comment: From what you are saying, DC current must be drawn equally across both capacitors for the voltages to remain balanced.

Comment: Yes the centre node cannot be loaded DC wise. But since you mention SMPS, indeed that 2nd circuit is often used in those to allow an easy design for both 110 V AC and 240 V AC. Then the 2nd circuit is the 240 V situation. What happens in those SMPSs is that the loading circuit is only using the top and bottom rails, so only drawing current from C1 and C2 **combined**. The centre node is usually connected to a half the supply voltage made by two large value resistors (1 M ohm or so) in series.

Comment: Why do that ? Because then C1 and C2 only need to be rated for halve the voltage compared to when C1 and C2 were only one capacitor. And a lower voltage rating makes a cap smaller and cheaper.

Comment: The purpose of this question is the modification of a 110VAC supply for 240V operation. On one hand it has a voltage doubler at its input, but on the other hand its switching IC attached across C2. I am trying to establish whether that has to be moved to the +325V line or can safely be left on the +162V centre point.

Comment: I'd have to see the schematic before daring to comment on that.

Comment: If you are really interested, it is here: http://techmattmillman.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/5150_PSU.png but in all seriousness, the burden of due diligence is very much on myself!

Comment: Of course I'm interested :-) Indeed the "hot" side of the transformer is on C2 which is half-wave charged from mains, C1 is in series with C2 and also half-wave charged making the doubled voltage (325 V). That voltage is only used outside this circuit ! So you're right that the switcher runs on 162 V, that (making 162 V DC) would be hard to achieve with a 240 V mains. I don't see an easy modification to make this supply work on 240 V.

Comment: Although the schematic doesn't show it, The +325V is directly connected to the primary winding of T2, so definitely is possible. A diagram of my proposed changes is here: http://techmattmillman.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/psu_refined_4.png

Comment: The +325V is connected to all places on the schematic with a square box labelled '1'

Comment: Indeed, the +325V connection is there but via a label. Are you relying on the voltage drop across the 2 22k resistors to make the 162 V DC for IC1_VCC ? If a nearly constant current flows into IC1_VCC then that could work. Do realize that if no current is drawn from IC1_VCC, the voltage will be 325 V.

Comment: What you have just highlighted is an very important point. What I suspect is, that the designers have worked out exactly how much current that block consumes, and that chain forms half of a voltage divider, so in theory by doubling its resistance it will be OK. Some experimentation on that is going to have to be performed to confirm that however!